# SMS Java Libraries

Tags: java, sms

I'm working a java desktop application for sending and receiving messages.Any one can help me with free Java libraries that will help my program run well.I also need to document the library information.SMS Gateway and SMSC all up and running , I just need to create a application that will run on both linux or windows server that can send and receive messages.This project is concerning mLearning.

Comment: Google is actually a terrible resource for information on SMS gateways.

Comment: @KeshavSaharia how is google of any relevance here?

Answer (score 1):

Since you chosen java as the language for your sms application, it should not be a big problem to work in linux and windows. Have you look into these java sms library?

- [SMSLib](http://smslib.org/)
- [smppapi](http://smppapi.sourceforge.net/)

The library above should come with a lot of example application that explain on how to make calls to send or receive sms.

You can also try the these SMSC simulator

- [SMSC simulator](http://opensmpp.logica.com/CommonPart/Download/download2.html) from Logica
- [smscsim](http://code.google.com/p/smscsim/)